# react-native-firebase Crashlytics getting error on Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-fabric, react-native-firebase

I followed the steps in https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/android for the react-native-firebase and specifically Crashlytics but when I run it on Android and try to use any of Crashlytics methods like `firebase.fabric.crashlytics().crash()` or `firebase.crashlytics().log('Some Error!');`

I get the following error

`Uncaught Error: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()`

Comment: Have you also done the Crashlytic specific installation steps ? -> https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/crashlytics/android

Comment: Yes I did that settings